# Hosting images on Dropbox

Tags: asp.net, dropbox-api, cloud-hosting

I'm looking for a server for hosting images from a webservice that i'm working on. This webservice will need to access the images many times, I'll upload about 4GB of images per day  to show to the users. My idea is to host the images over there and get the public links to put on the HTML.

So I'd like to know if Dropbox is an adequate tool for this, because I was studying the Dropbox API and I think It doesn't offer adequate tools to get the images's public link.

Summarizing my question, are these kind of hosts for this kind of services or not?

Comment: You really want to use a Content Delivery Network (CDN) for this. Akamai and Amazon Cloud Services come to mind, but there are others as well...I think of Dropbox as filesharing, not a CDN...

Comment: Why not just host the images with your web service? And then host your web service in one of the clouds that Tim mentioned (or Azure, since you tagged this ASP.NET)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other comments and answers say, a normal CDN is probably a better choice for this.

For reference though, the Dropbox API does let you get publicly shareable links to files:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares

You can also modify these links as desired:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

There's also a direct and temporary version:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media

Note however that there are bandwidth limits on these links:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/4204

Also, the API enables you to access file content directly:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET

Answer (score 0):

Try amazon web services http://aws.amazon.com/s3/
Lots of big websites use this for serving images. It is very fast!