# how to use dropbox to host images for a phonegap app?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, cordova, dropbox

so i am building an app using node.js express and using postgres. I was thinking if it is possible to host my images on dropbox and instead of storing the image on the database i was thinking of storing the dropbox URL in the database. Now i am not sure if that is possible if it is can someone please give me a link where i can look at a tutorial or example and if it is not possible is there any other way of hosting images on a site and simply storing the url on the database?
sorry if i have confused anyone, i am new to this

Comment: I answered a more or less equivalent question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971793/hosting-images-on-dropbox/28972220#28972220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through this same issue yesterday, so hopefully my answer helps.

**Step 1**: Find the image file in your dropbox and click "Share"

[image]

**Step 2**: In the popup, copy the link

[image]

**Step 3**: Remove the `?dl=0` and add `?raw=1`

For me, my URL changed from:

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyqpia7u92oto9d/Logox128%20copy.jpg?dl=0`

to:

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyqpia7u92oto9d/Logox128%20copy.jpg?raw=1`

**Step 4**: You should be able to put the link in your database now.