# How to show a specific error when assigning src= "@URL.action"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this event:

```
function onChange(productName) {
  $("#itemImage img").attr('src', "@Url.Action("GetCustomProductImage")" + "?productName=" + productName);
}
```

My controller method can throw an exception when the image cannot be loaded(there can be multiple reasons but the main one is whe the image doesn't exist) and I can see it in the browser console.

It is important to say that the image does not exist in any server directory and i don't want to store it, i'm retrieven it as an array of bytes from a dropbox shared folder.

But I'm having trouble displaying a message user friendly in the view.
Since the response from my controller is stored in src i can't access the error info.

Using the events `on("error")` or `img.onerror` does not give any information about the error.

If I return `Content("<script>alert("+errormessage+");</script>")` it does not show the alert.

I want to avoid doing multiple calls to the server so ajax to check for errors and then assigning the src doesn't suit me.

I also want to avoid converting the img to base 64 and then assigning it to the src because the img gets much larger.

i'm asking for an impossible here or there is a way to show an error message on the view I haven't thought of?

If it is too confusing please point it out and i will try to explain myself in a better way. Thanks.

Comment: you mean it's an exception because the image doesn't exist or something?

Comment: yes, sorry, i will edit it.

Comment: I agree the onerror doesn't directly give you information about the error, but do you need to show that to the user? You can just display a general "Sorry, an unexpected error occurred" type of message. Users usually don't want to see technical error messages.

Comment: In this case i would like to tell the users wheter the image was not found on the dropbox shared folder or the file is too big or "standard error something happened". I can identify those errors on the controller.

Comment: well unfortunately I don't think you can do that by this method, unless someone else with extra knowledge can contradict me. All you know is that there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an image `src` to hold a `@Url.Action()` - it's not necessary and is incorrect html.

Some `$.ajax` should work to achieve what you want. You can elaborate on a proper return model if you wish (for example, to rely simply no string responses) but this, or a more specific version of it, should achieve what you're after:

```
<div id="itemImage">
    <img src="/path/to/initial-image.png" />
</div>

<button id="test-button">TEST</button>

<script>
    $("#test-button").on("click", function () {
        onChange("test-product-name");
    });

    function onChange(productName) {
        var url = "@Url.Action("GetCustomProductImage")";
        $.ajax({
            url: url + "?productName=" + productName,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (transport) {
                if (transport !== "false") {
                    $("#itemImage img").attr('src', transport);
                } else {
                    $("#itemImage").text("Could not be retrieved");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("ERROR");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

With a Controller Action of:

```
public JsonResult GetCustomProductImage(string productName)
{
    // Get image src from productSrc - ideally, build a Json return model
    // EITHER:
    var transport = "/Path/To/image.png";
    // OR:
    //var transport = "false";
    return Json(transport, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Based on your updated question, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28972220/5957979) useful as a point of reference to get either a reference to the Dropbox-hosted image or to download the file to the server and reference that.

Comment: This is a good answer but i'm afraid i didn't express the question well enough.

Comment: i added the edit, the image is in an array of bytes not in a server directory, so i can't use this solution.

Comment: "Don't use an image src to hold a @Url.Action()"...why? It just resolves to a string containing a URL.

Comment: I haven't referenced Dropbox images before, but if it's similar to Blobs (which it probably is) you should be able to either download the image to the server and reference that OR (maybe better) just reference the image at Dropbox having retrieved the url reference. Either way, it should be possible for a non-private folder and GetCustomProductImage would have to do that work.